# Is there an order to prepositional phrases?

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases, phrase-order

Which statement is correct?

1. The change adds more info to the changelog about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx.

Or:

2. The change adds more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx to the changelog.

Comment: Neither is a sentence. It is unclear what meaning you wish to express. Can you explain?

Comment: Please [edit] to explain in your own words what the statement is referring to. What do you think the particular difficulties are with each version?

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical, so the question would come down to which version expresses the information more clearly.  "The (programming?) change adds additional information retroactively to the Change Log for commits from May xx, xxxx".

Comment: Both are grammatically correct (though some people here are confused by the technical terminology--"commit" is a noun here). Voting to reopen since there is an interesting question here: since "more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx" is a complete noun phrase in (2), why can we break it up into parts in (1)?

Comment: placement of prepositional phrases

Comment: @Lambie is right: it’s about the placement not the internal phrase order.  Yes, there is an order to prepositional phrases: the preposition has to come before the noun phrase which is its object. Otherwise it would be a postpositional phrase not a prepositional phrase. Compare *“**after** three years”*   with *“three years **ago**”*. You can't switch the order of the adposition and have it mean the same thing, certain well-known exceptions like this one ***notwithstanding***. :)   And yes, this is a joke not an answer.

Comment: Yes, there is: the head of a PP normally occurs in front position followed by its complement. One exception is the prep "ago", which invariably follows its complement. Thus, "two weeks ago" is a PP where "two weeks" is complement of "ago".

Comment: I have run across this kind of language before, and I always wonder how anyone can get any work done. Although both sentences are grammatical, neither is useful. "This adds more information to the changelog. It refers to the previous commits on May xx, xxxx." Or whatever you really mean. Stringing prepositional phrases together is confusing to the reader, no matter in what order they appear.

Answer (score 9):

First: some commenters got confused by the technical language in this sentence. *Commit* here is a noun, referring to a record of a batch of changes to a codebase; the sentence is talking about the commits made on some date "May xx, xxxx." A *changelog* is a written listing of the differences between versions of a piece of software. One would often add information related to codebase changes to such a changelog, which explains the sentence's meaning.

On to the main topic: there's a substantial difference between these two sentences:

1. The change adds more info to the changelog about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx.
2. The change adds more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx to the changelog.

In version (2), "more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx" is a single noun phrase; "about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx" modifies "info," and within that "on May xx, xxxx" modifies "commits." "To the changelog," though, is a separate modifier (or rather complement) of the verb "adds."

So, what's going on in version (1)? Why can we break up the noun phrase into pieces like that? The answer is that (1) contains a **postposing** construction. In this construction, some element within a clause is extracted from its usual location and moved to (or near to) the end of the clause. In this case, the prepositional phrase "about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx" has been extracted from the noun phrase and shifted to the end of the sentence.

One reason we use postposing is to keep "heavy" constituents, ones that are particularly long or complex, at the end of the clause ([Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), pp. 1382-1383). Consider these two examples that Huddleston & Pullum give:

3. You’ll find the report that the company has prepared in response to the secretary's latest allegations on your desk.
4. You’ll find on your desk the report that the company has prepared in response to the secretary's latest allegations.

In (3), the object ("the report...allegations") occurs in its normal position immediately after the verb. However, this sounds quite awkward, since that noun phrase is so much heavier than the following locative "on your desk." So instead, we would typically prefer version (4), where the object is postposed.

Now, in *your* example, I think either the postposed version (1) or the more ordinary version (2) would be acceptable; certainly "to the changelog" is less heavy than "more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx," but (2) is nowhere near as bad as (3) above. But, as Paul Tannenbaum notes in his answer, there's a third option here:

5. The change adds to the changelog more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx.

In (5), the *entire* noun phrase "more info about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx" has been postposed, not just the prepositional phrase "about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx." This moves an even heavier constituent to the end of the clause, and it keeps the whole noun phrase together, so it may be preferable to either (1) or (2).

Comment: The change adds more info to the changelog about the previous commits on May xx, xxxx. I think that order is standard. I don't see any moving. That's where it comes in the sequence. This play activates more passions in people about previous works by the same author.

Comment: @Lambie Importantly: we aren't talking about a changelog about the commits, we're talking about *information* about the commits; that information, about the commits, is being added to the changelog. That's by far the most sensible interpretation given the way these terms are used in technical contexts.

Comment: Grammatically, "commits" can be any x noun, and No. 1 is still the best.

Comment: I find (5) _significantly_ more awkward and cumbersome than (1) and (2). Albeit not as significantly, I also find (4) less natural – or at least more formal – than (3), which I don’t find awkward at all. Having long constituents intervene can of course lead to very awkward sentences, but I don’t think (3) is an example.

Answer (score 6):

Both are **grammatically** correct. Your second is the clearer. And clearer still would be

> The change adds to the change log more info about the previous commits on May *xx*, *xxxx*.

This version has the prepositional phrase *to the changelog* contiguous with the verb *adds* so as to keep all of the sentence’s new information together at the end.

Note that in some other contexts it is better to have the direct object be the element contiguous with the verb and put the prepositional phrase at the end. Thus, *He **wrote his next novel** in German*. Although placing the prepositional phrase before the direct object is less frequent in casual speech and tends not to work well—if at all—in shorter sentences, it can be very helpful for clarifying one’s meaning in written texts. For example, in the introduction of an essay about one of an author’s early novels and why it was significant, the sentence, *He wove **into it** three themes that would feature prominently in all of his subsequent works*, is appropriate, and moving **into it** to the end would degrade the sentence’s flow.

As a further note about your sentence, even in my proposed version there still remains ambiguity. What happened on that May day? The commits, their original logging, or the addition of the further information? Depending on the pragmatic context, this detail (ambiguity) might be unimportant. But without that context there cannot exist a definitive answer to your question, “Which is correct?”

Comment: Although this is unlikely to be undesirable in OP's use case, it's worth noting (in case they're ESL) that letting a PP intervene between the verb and direct object like that does ring markedly formal.

Comment: @UnrelatedString, I have edited my answer to accommodate (what I took to be) your point.

Comment: I disagree that the second is clearer; it can be read as concerning *commits to the changelog*.

Answer (score 2):

If it’s not a changelog about previous commits, then your second example is clearer. Perhaps you can see that better comparing these simpler examples:

> *The edit adds more info **to the article about the storm on Tuesday**.*
>  (The article is about the storm on Tuesday.)
>
> *The edit adds more info **about the storm on Tuesday** to the article.*
>  (The additional info is about the storm on Tuesday.)
>
> *The change adds more info **to the changelog about the previous commits on 1 May 2023**.*
>  (The changelog is about the previous
> commits on 1 May 2023.)
>
> *The change adds more info **about the previous commits on 1 May 2023** to the changelog.*
>  (The additional info is about the
> previous commits on 1 May 2023.)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no fixed order for prepositional phrases. The arrangement often depends on the specific context and the writer's choice.

Comment: Ok, but that's just like your opinion. Can you [edit] to add anything to back this up?