# Can an adverbial phrase of place be put before a direct object?

Tags: grammar

This is for a translation of a technical document, where the direct object has modifiers that make it exceedingly long (that cannot be dismantled due to a need to match the source material in a foreign language). As an example...

The robot displayed a program for exterminating the human race in a case where carbon emissions are not curtailed and the fate of the earth is threatened on a projector.

Could this be written as...

The robot displayed on a projector a program for exterminating the human race in a case where carbon emissions are not curtailed and the fate of the earth is threatened.

Are commas necessary around ", on a projector," for this order?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Yes. Does this answer help? https://english.stackexchange.com/a/615140/470858 -- In this case it's a noun phrase being postposed, not a prepositional phrase, but the basic principle is the same.

Comment: Yes, that is perfect! The "on your desk" which is moved in the second set of example sentences is very similar to what I'm thinking of, and it seems okay even without the commas. I appreciate the explanation of using a postposing (edit: typo) construction as well.

Comment: I find this construction vaguely foreign, but it's common in technical writing where too much distance between the adverbial phrase and the noun it modifies can be even more difficult to parse than the odd word order.

Comment: You put the *projector* way out in left field; it's just strange.

Comment: Why not this: On a projector, the robot displayed a program …"

Comment: It depends how important the projector is, with at the front being most important, and if it's not at all important, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of thing (displayed on a projector a program ...) happens fairly often in formal writing though it sounds wooden.  Less wooden choices are either to start the sentence with "On a projector" or to reorder the sentence, if your original context permits:

For example:

> Displayed on a projector by the robot was a program for exterminating the human race in case carbon emissions had not been  reduced and the fate of the earth was threatened.

Answer (score -1):

I commented:

> Yes. [Does this answer help?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/615140/470858) -- In this case it's a noun phrase being postposed, not a prepositional phrase, but the basic principle is the same.

The asker replied:

> Yes, that is perfect! The "on your desk" which is moved in the second set of example sentences is very similar to what I'm thinking of, and it seems okay even without the commas. I appreciate the explanation of using a postposing construction as well.

It appears the question may have been resolved.