# What other types of words have free word order?

Tags: word-order

What types of words allow the speaker to choose where they want to use it? I can only think of adverbs, where it is acceptable to say "we moved slowly" or "we slowly moved." Are there any other types of words that also have free word order?

Comment: What do you mean by "free word order"? There are very few words that can occur *everywhere* in a sentence, and very many that can be moved around in different ways. See for instance my answer [about postposing constructions.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/615140/470858)

Comment: 'We went often to the secret grove' is fine while 'We went seldom to the secret grove' is unacceptable. Different adverbs , even, have different distributions. / 'The plane didn't  land on the proper runway' means something different from 'The plane didn't land on the runway proper.' / 'It was blamed on the adults responsible' means something different from 'It was blamed on the responsible adults'. But 'the required amount' and 'the amount required' are closely synonymous.  // That said, I'd agree that adverbs seem to have the freest distribution overall.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Lies by chance your secret grove in the forest primeval? :) *This is the forest primeval. The murmuring pines and the hemlocks, /
Bearded with moss, and in garments green, indistinct in the twilight, /
Stand like Druids of eld, with voices sad and prophetic, /
Stand like harpers hoar, with beards that rest on their bosoms. /
Loud from its rocky caverns, the deep-voiced neighboring ocean / 
Speaks, and in accents disconsolate answers the wail of the forest.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is a so called *fixed word-order language*, and instances where two given word orders result in a strictly identical meaning must be rare (except as regards adverbs, as you noticed). For instance the two sentences below, with a different word order mean roughly the same thing, the second includes a certain nuance that will be derived from the context.

- Julie buys her vegetables in the market.
- Her vegetables Julie buys in the market.

Besides adverbs, there is another area where this principle has a wide applicability; this is the grammar of multi word verbs: the object and the adverbial particle can be placed indifferently after one another (when the length of the object is reasonably short).

- He picked up the book.
- He picked the book up.
- He picked the huge cat up.
- He picked the screeching and scratching black cat up. (*a bit long but still acceptable*)
- <s>He picked the screeching and scratching black cat on the dining table up.</s> (*too long*)

Note that if the object is a pronoun there is no option of placing the particle before the pronoun (remark by [user Henry](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/620006/what-other-types-of-words-have-free-word-order/620011?noredirect=1#comment1576699_620011)).

- picked it up, give it up, take them down,…

The order "particle before object" seems to be much preferred.

[image]

[image]

There is also, among other rare cases and as a case of lesser importance, the following possibility (strictly no difference in meaning). This is possible in the case of nouns that can appear either in a premodifying  or  appositive function in the particular context of rivers, but not all rivers.

> **CoGEL § 17.89** Some rivers allow either strict apposition  or premodification
> • the (River) Rhine/Thames/Seine/Rhône/Nile
> New-world rivers have the proper noun before the descriptor:
> • the Mississippi (River), the Ohio (River), the Potomac (River)

Note: It is not clear whether the River Running that is being talked about in *The Hobbit* by J.R.R. Tolkien, can also be named "the Running River"; if I remember well, this second possibility is not found in the book. This is to say that it is not necessarily the case that both orders are possible when the order "River < name >" exists.

**Addition**

The above comment from [user Edwin Ashwood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/620006/what-other-types-of-words-have-free-word-order/620011?noredirect=1#comment1576661_620006) prompted the following addition.

*Adjectives ending in *-able* and *-ible* in certain constructions*

**CoGEL § 7.21** Adjectives ending in *-able* and *-ible* can have postposition when the noun is identified by another adjective in the superlative degree, by *only*, or by the general ordinals *last*, *next*, etc. We this have either attributive position or posposition in:

- the best *possible* // the best use *possible*
- the greatest *imaginable* insult // the greatest insult *imaginable*
- the best *available* person // the best person *available*
- the only *suitable* actor // the only actor *suitable*

*Individual cases of adjectives*

**CoGEL § 7.21** *Appointed, desired, required; following, past, preceding*, also occur in either position:

- at the *appointed* time // at the time *appointed*
- in past years // in years past
- the *preceding* years // the years *preceding*
- *positive* proof // proof *positive*

Comment: A little explanation for the minus vote would help.; curious to know…

Comment: Surely the final and longest black cat sentence is no less understandable, even if it sounds a little perverse.  The famous example is: "What did you bring that book I didn't want to be read to out of up for?" It sounds funny. But "For what did you bring up that book out of which I did not wish to be read to?" sounds amusingly stilted.

Comment: Trivially, exceptions in the US are the River Raisin and the River Rouge [French derivation].  // More importantly (and not using the ill-defined 'phrasal verb'), there are some MWVs that are inseparable (he looked after the children/them well; we came across some old coins) and some that are obligatorily separable (Don't worry about her exams: we'll get Jill through somehow.) (And some don't like the MWV analysis at all.) // A reasonable answer to an over-broad question. Perhaps the DV-er didn't think OSVLoc etc ordering was a true example.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did remember that remark you made once about the term "phrasal verb", although I am rather unable now to explain why it is undesirable, and I tried to take it into account, but couldn't remember a term that seemed appropriate; the best I could come up with was "prepositional verb", but it is not satisfactory, and so I used "phrasal verb". ("phrasal" would be too general a term?)

Comment: It is worth noting that you would not say ["picked up it" rather "picked it up"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=picked+it+up%2Cpicked+up+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).  It is also interesting that picking things up seems to have become more popular recently.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that the question is far too broad; each of these is its own type of thing, and so it is not possible to say which "types" of words allow for variation in word order. There are just too many possibilities. Not to mention *Río Grande, Mesa Verde, Sierra Nevada*. :)  // Remember that you can't put a pronoun at the end of the separable transitive verbs you mention, so for example it ᴍᴜꜱᴛ be *turn it off, pick her up, drop them off* — ɴᴇᴠᴇʀ *turn off ❌it, pick up ❌her, drop off ❌them*.

Comment: Claudia Claridge wrote the monumental 'Multi-Word Verbs in Early Modern English'. The title belies the fact that modern English is covered extremely well, but reflects her assessment that 'phrasal verb' is used inconsistently and is thus unhelpful. In fact, she spends pages discussing the history of the terminology involved.  // Where MWV + DO stops and V + PP begins is always a bone of contention.

Comment: @tchrist This is the type of question that you can  determine as yielding a profusion of cases only after you've began to pile up a substantial number of them. For the time being, I can see nothing else than what I manage to round up in this answer, and it does not amount to such a whole lot. Also, it is not necessary to take "type" as too specific, but perhaps the original poster should change it to something like "cases".

Comment: Hey, I'm the one who upvoted your answer!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Those are  bones of contention that I am being made aware of  at last;  my tries at categorization have often enough be nagging failures; I understand now that the difficulty does not lie solely in my inexperience.

Comment: The cohesiveness of the [simplex verb] + [preposition/particle/whatsit]: unary, binary, or is a gradience model possible (66% a compound)?